# ¿Cómo simplificar este código debido a una variación de criterio usando Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, gson

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Android que recibe un JSON desde el servidor y lo parsea a varias clases usando Gson.

La dificultad la tengo en esta parte del JSON:

```
            "salmodia": {
                "tipo": 0,
                "salmos": [{
                    "orden": "1",
                    "antifona": "«El cielo y la tierra pasarán, mis palabras no pasarán», dice el Señor.",
                    "ref": "Salmo 118, 81-88",
                    "tema": "",
                    "intro": "",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "Me consumo ansiando tu salvación,_y espero en tu palabra;_mis ojos se consumen ansiando tus promesas,_mientras digo: ¿cuándo me consolarás?_Estoy como un odre puesto al humo,_pero no olvido tus leyes.§¿Cuántos serán los días de tu siervo?_¿Cuándo harás justicia de mis perseguidores._Me han cavado fosas los insolentes, ignorando tu voluntad;_todos tus mandatos son leales,_sin razón me persiguen, protégeme.§Casi dieron conmigo en la tumba,_pero yo no abandoné tus decretos; por tu bondad dame vida,_para que observe los preceptos de tu boca."
                }, {
                    "orden": "2",
                    "antifona": "Tú eres, Señor, mi refugio y mi bastión contra el enemigo.",
                    "ref": "Salmo 60",
                    "tema": "Oración de un desterrado",
                    "intro": "Oración del justo~que espera la vida eterna.~(S. Hilario)",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "Dios mío, escucha mi clamor,_atiende a mi súplica;_te invoco desde el confín de la tierra_con el corazón abatido:§llévame a una roca inaccesible,_porque tú eres mi refugio_y mi bastión contra el enemigo.§Habitaré siempre en tu morada,_refugiado al amparo de tus alas;_porque tú, ¡oh Dios!, escucharás mis deseos_y me darás la heredad de los que veneran tu nombre.§Añade días a los días del rey,_que sus años alcancen varias generaciones;_que reine siempre en presencia de Dios,_que tu gracia y tu lealtad le hagan guardia.§Yo tañeré siempre en tu honor,_e iré cumpliendo mis votos día tras día."
                }, {
                    "orden": "3",
                    "antifona": "Protege mi vida, Señor, del terrible enemigo.",
                    "ref": "Salmo 63",
                    "tema": "Súplica contra los enemigos",
                    "intro": "Este salmo se aplica especialmente~a la pasión del Señor.~(S. Agustín)",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "Escucha, ¡oh Dios!, la voz de mi lamento,_protege mi vida del terrible enemigo;_escóndeme de la conjura de los perversos_y del motín de los malhechores:§afilan sus lenguas como espadas_y disparan como flechas palabras venenosas,_para herir a escondidas al inocente,_para herirlo por sorpresa y sin riesgo.§Se animan al delito,_calculan cómo esconder trampas,_y dicen: «¿quién lo descubrirá?»_Inventan maldades y ocultan sus invenciones,_porque su mente y su corazón no tienen fondo.§Pero Dios los acribilla a flechazos,_por sorpresa los cubre de heridas;_su misma lengua los lleva a la ruina,_y los que lo ven menean la cabeza.§Todo el mundo se atemoriza,_proclama la obra de Dios_y medita sus acciones.§El justo se alegra con el Señor,_se refugia en Él,_y se felicitan los rectos de corazón."
                }]
            }
```

La clave `salmodia` es mapeada a una clase `Salmodia` que tiene a su vez una lista de objetos `Salmo`.

Ahora bien, hay casos en los que debo leer cada `Salmo` con todos sus elementos, dándoles formatos específicos.

Esto lo hago con un método `getSalmoCompleto()`, que he escrito dentro de la clase `Salmodia`.

El método hace algo como esto:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto() {

    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
    String salmo = "";
    String preant = "";
    String ant = "";

    for (SalmoCompleto s : salmoCompleto) {
        SpannableStringBuilder tema = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder parte = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder intro = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder ref = new SpannableStringBuilder("");

        preant = "Ant. " + s.getOrden() + ". ";
        ant = " " + Utils.getAntifonaLimpia(s.getAntifona());
        if (!s.getTema().equals("")) {
            tema.append(Utils.toRed(s.getTema()));
            tema.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        if (!s.getIntro().equals("")) {
            intro.append(Utils.fromHtmlSmall(s.getIntro()));
            intro.append(Utils.LS2);
        }
        if (!s.getParte().equals("")) {
            parte.append(Utils.toRed(s.getParte()));
            parte.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        if (!s.getRef().equals("")) {
            ref.append(s.getRef());
            ref.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        sb.append(Utils.toRed(preant));
        sb.append(Utils.fromHtml(s.getAntifona()));
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);
        sb.append(ref);
        sb.append(tema);
        sb.append(intro);
        sb.append(parte);
        salmo = Utils.getFormato(s.getSalmo());
        sb.append(Utils.fromHtml(salmo));
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);

        if (s.getSalmo().endsWith("∸")) {
            sb.append(Utils.getNoGloria());
        } else {
            sb.append(Utils.getFinSalmo());
        }
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);
        sb.append(Utils.toRed("Ant. "));
        sb.append(ant);
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);
    }
    return sb;

}
```

La cuestión es que cada elemento de cada salmo tiene que tener formatos, colores o tamaños de letra específicos... todo eso funciona bien.

Mi dificultad es la siguiente: cuando el tipo de salmodia es diferente de cero, yo debo construir los elementos de forma diferente.

Por ejemplo, si la salmodia es del tipo `1`, yo debo entonces mostrar casi todo igual que como hago con el `for` de más arriba, salvo en un elemento: **en vez de mostrar tres antífonas debo mostrar una sola, y esa antífona que debo mostrar depende de otro valor numérico (si es `1`, debo mostrar solamente la antífona 1, si es `2` la antífona 2, y así sucesivamente ...).**

En otras palabras, el `for` de más arriba me serviría (casi), excepto por el problema que ya comenté sobre la antífona, que en determinados casos debe mostrarse una sola vez y no tres veces. O sea, hay casos en que una sola antífona debe englobar a todos los elementos que hay dentro de `salmo` y esa antífona puede ser la 1, la 2, la 3 ... según el caso.

¿Cómo puedo simplificar esas evaluaciones, evitando repetir una y otra vez código parecido al del `for`?

Espero no haberme liado demasiado. Si hay alguna duda pregunten en comentarios.

#### Ejemplo en la App de un salmo normal

Empieza el primer salmo con todos sus elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Termina el primero y sigue el segundo con todos sus elementos. Aquí vemos que, al final del salmo uno se repite de nuevo la antífona. Luego comienza el salmo 2 con su antífona  y todos sus elementos y así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el funcionamiento normal. Mientras que, en el funcionamiento anormal, lo que quiero es los tres salmos con todos sus elementos, menos la antífona, que irá solamente al principio de los tres salmos y sin número y al final de los tres salmos.

Algo así:

```
Ant. El cielo y la tierra pasarán, mis palabras no pasarán», dice el Señor.

    Todo el Salmo 1 y sus elementos
    Todo el Salmo 2 y sus elementos
    Todo el Salmo 3 y sus elementos
    Todo el Salmo N... y sus elementos

Ant. El cielo y la tierra pasarán, mis palabras no pasarán», dice el Señor.
```

Comment: has intentado meter eso en un metodo diferente donde te devuelva el objeto construido en base a los parametros ?

Comment: @elporfirio el método que hace eso es `getSalmoCompleto`. Lo que quiero es precisamente reutilizar ese método, no crear un método distinto por cada condición. Las variaciones son pocas y no quiero tener `n`  métodos como `getSalmoCompletoSituacion1()`, `getSalmoCompletoSituacion2()`, `getSalmoCompletoSituacionN()`, sino evaluar todo dentro de un mismo método controlando cada situación y, si fuera posible usando un mismo `for`

Comment: yo pensaba algo mas como `getSalmoCompleto(options)` antes de ello yo lo que haria seria genera el objeto de los que se alimenta  a partir del objeto JSON/GSON dependiendo del valor numerico que dices `1,2, etc` a partir de ahi ya solo me traigo lo necesario, sin evaluar si esta en empty o no.  Lo siguiente que haria seria crear un formateador, es decir el objeto ya esta construido y solo debo aplicar los estilos visuales.

Comment: @elporfirio mi JSON está tomado conforme a mi modelo de datos y lo mismo el mapeo que hace Gson. No puedo bajo ningún concepto alterar el modelo de datos. Lo único cambiante es la cuestión de la antifona, que en unos casos se debe mostrar una por cada salmo y en otros una que los englobe a todos. Viendo las cosas más de cerca creo que puedo trabajar eso partiendo del método `getAntifona` del objeto `SalmoCompleto`... Puedo pasar a `getAntifona` un parámetro `options` para que me traiga las tres o una sola según el caso, aunque quedaría pendiente cambiar el formato en el  `for` ...

Comment: Padre, tendrías a bien mostrar al menos una de las variaciones, tengo algunas ideas pero el lenguaje me enreda un poco. Creo que viendo el código me quedará más claro y quizás pueda ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate gracias por el interés,¿qué parte del código quieres que te muestre? Entiendo que me extendí demasiado en al explicación, el núcleo del problema es que: en algunos casos se debe mostrar todo normal, como hace el método `getSalmoCompleto`, pero hay casos en que todo es casi normal, sólo que la `antifona` no se muestra seguida de cada salmo, sino una sola para todos los salmos que haya. En ese caso cambia también la posición de la misma (en el StringBuilder). Es básicamente eso lo que quiero manejar de una forma simple.

Comment: Si, creo que comprendo la idea. Lo que te pido es que nos muestres como quedaría el código para manejar el _caso 1_, si hubieses hecho otro método `getSalmoCompletoCaso1`, que sé que es lo que se busca evitar. Es para hacerme una idea más aterrizada de lo que variaría, pues quizás ando algo espeso hoy con el lenguaje natural. :)

Comment: @jachguate no he escrito ningún simulacro de `getSalmoCompletoCaso1` porque precisamente lo quiero evitar. Pero sería exactamente igual que `getSalmoCompleto`, pero sacando la construcción de la antífona del `for`, para ponerla **rodeando todo el resto del contenido de todos los salmos en la lista**, tanto al principio como al final. Algo así: *`(a) Antifona (única) correspondiente - > (b) Todo el resto del contenido de los N salmos que haya (construido en el for)  -> (c)De nuevo la antífona (única) correspondiente, cuyo texto es el mismo de (a)`*

Comment: Ok, entiendo, si no es en código, al menos poder ver el _resultado_ de ambos métodos. En realidad lo leí varias veces y no me termina de quedar claro (quizás porque no tengo idea de como se _muestra_ un salmo). Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate ahora pongo unas capturas de pantalla.

Comment: @jachguate a ver si ahora se entiende mejor el asunto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86567/discussion-between-jachguate-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoy, con las ideas más claras, he podido encontrar una solución. No sé si es la mejor, pero hace lo que necesito.

Se trata simplemente de preguntar si la salmodia es del tipo `1` o no, para poner alrededor de los `n` salmos que haya la antífona que corresponda.

En ese caso, hago el `append` fuera del bucle:

```
    if (tipo == 1) {
        sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona));
        antUnica = salmoCompleto.get(hourIndex).getAntifona();
        sb.append(antUnica);
    }
```

En cuanto a la antífona que hay que elegir, la cual depende del valor de `hourIndex`, la tomo del array de antífonas con esto:

```
        antUnica = salmoCompleto.get(hourIndex).getAntifona();
```

Cuando el tipo de salmodia es normal, cada antífona de cada salmo se coloca en el lugar que le corresponda, dentro del bucle con este código:

```
        if (tipo != 1) {
            sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona + s.getOrden() + ". "));
            sb.append(Utils.fromHtml(s.getAntifona()));
        }
```

No sé si sea la mejor forma. Pero funciona y se mantiene intacto el modelo de datos.

Este sería el método completo. Gracias a quienes se interesaron por el problema, sobre todo a @jachguate ([una pregunta tuya en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47878108#47878108) me abrió un camino de respuesta).

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto(int hourIndex) {
    int tipo = this.tipo;
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
    String salmo = "";
    String preAntifona = "Ant. ";
    String antUnica = "";

    if (tipo == 1) {
        sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona));
        antUnica = salmoCompleto.get(hourIndex).getAntifona();
        sb.append(antUnica);
    }
    for (SalmoCompleto s : salmoCompleto) {
        SpannableStringBuilder tema = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder parte = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder intro = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
        SpannableStringBuilder ref = new SpannableStringBuilder("");

        if (tipo != 1) {
            sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona + s.getOrden() + ". "));
            sb.append(Utils.fromHtml(s.getAntifona()));
        }

        if (!s.getTema().equals("")) {
            tema.append(Utils.toRed(s.getTema()));
            tema.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        if (!s.getIntro().equals("")) {
            intro.append(Utils.fromHtmlSmall(s.getIntro()));
            intro.append(Utils.LS2);
        }
        if (!s.getParte().equals("")) {
            parte.append(Utils.toRed(s.getParte()));
            parte.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        if (!s.getRef().equals("")) {
            ref.append(s.getRef());
            ref.append(Utils.LS2);
        }

        sb.append(Utils.LS2);
        sb.append(ref);
        sb.append(tema);
        sb.append(intro);
        sb.append(parte);
        salmo = Utils.getFormato(s.getSalmo());
        sb.append(Utils.fromHtml(salmo));
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);

        if (s.getSalmo().endsWith("∸")) {
            sb.append(Utils.getNoGloria());
        } else {
            sb.append(Utils.getFinSalmo());
        }
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);

        if (tipo != 1) {
            sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona));
            sb.append(Utils.getAntifonaLimpia(s.getAntifona()));
            sb.append(Utils.LS2);

        }
    }
    if (tipo == 1) {
        sb.append(Utils.toRed(preAntifona));
        antUnica = Utils.getAntifonaLimpia(salmoCompleto.get(hourIndex).getAntifona());
        sb.append(antUnica);
        sb.append(Utils.LS2);

    }
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, aunque en realidad creo que el crédito está de más pues la solución es tuya. Un saludo. :)