# ¿Se pueden pasar argumentos predeterminados u opcionales en Java como se hace en PHP?

Tags: java

Tengo un método en Java en el que a veces necesito usar un valor numérico, pero a veces no.

En PHP existe algo que se llama **Valores de argumentos predeterminados**, donde se puede hacer algo así ([ejemplo del mismo Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php)):

```
<?php
function hacer_café($tipo = "capuchino")
{
    return "Hacer una taza de $tipo.\n";
}
echo hacer_café();
echo hacer_café(null);
echo hacer_café("espresso");
?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
Hacer una taza de capuchino.
Hacer una taza de .
Hacer una taza de espresso.
```

En Java me da error:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto(int hourIndex=0) {
    //Evaluar hourIndex y resto del código 
}
```

La idea es poder llamar al método tanto así:

```
getSalmoCompleto();
```

Como así:

```
getSalmoCompleto(n);
```

Donde `n` es un número cualquiera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java no soporta Argumentos opciones hasta la fecha. Pero puedes utilizar la sobrecarga de métodos donde defines uno sin argumentos y le envías el valor por defecto al que si acepta el argumento:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto() {
    getSalmoCompleto(0);
}
public SpannableStringBuilder getSalmoCompleto(int hourIndex) {
    //Evaluar hourIndex y resto del código 
}
```

Y asi puedes ejecutar el metodo como deseas:

```
getSalmoCompleto() // se envia 0 por defecto.
```

Comment: Excelente Einer, muchísimas gracias, funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 3):

Si bien la respuesta de @Einer es correcta, en java se puede definir un método para pasar un array de algún tipo disfrazado de "numero incierto de parámetros", que podria usarse para simular parámetros optativos:

```
public void unMetodo(String ... argumentos){
    // argumentos es un vector de String
}
```

Cando se llama este método se hace de esta forma:

```
...
unMetodo("Hola", null,"Mundo"); // Podría haber más parámetros String
...
```

Con esta llamada el método recibe el vector argumentos como `{"hola",null,"Mundo"}`;

Si en lugar de `String` fuera `Object` el tipo de dato, en teoría podria pasar argumentos de cualquier tipo (y luego castearlos dentro del método)

Algo así:

```
/*
Parametros: String nombre, int edad, Date fechaDeNacimiento
*/
public void metodoConParametrosOpcioneales(Object ... params){
    //Defaults
    String nombre = "Natalia Natalia";
    int edad  = -1;
    Date = null;
    if(params.length > 0) nombre = (String) params[0];
    if(params.length > 1) edad = (int) params[1];
    if(params.length > 2) nombre = (Date) params[2];

    // Resto de la lógica del método  

}
```

Luego si llamanos:

```
metodoConParametrosOpcioneales("Juan");
```

Dentro del método se seteará solo el nombre y tanto edad como fecha de nacimiento tendrán el valor default.

**EDICION I**

> No entiendo del todo lo que quieres decir con que pierdo el chequeo
>   del tipo de datos. En cuanto al uso, es para algo muy concreto
>   (planteado en esta pregunta). Realmente, es para dos tipos de casos,
>   en uno llamaré al método pasándole un argumento hourIndex y en otros
>   llamaré al método sin ningún argumento. En ese sentido la respuesta de
>   @Einer responde completamente a ese requerimiento.

1. En php no hay chequeo del tipo de dato de los parámetros, si una funcion que tiene que recibir un `boolean` para hacer algo, recibe un `int` simplemente se rompe en tiempo de ejecución.
   En java, un método como el planteado por @Einer, se chequea en tiempo de compilación, si pasas un `int` donde tiene que ir un `boolean`, el programa no compila.
   La alternativa que estoy exponiendo funciona como php en ese sentido, se puede llamar la funcion con cualquier tipo de dato y si noe es el correcto dará una excepción en tiempo de ejecución.
2. Con caso puntual quise decir que no está bueno perder el chequeo de datos y por eso yo no lo usaría a lo largo de todo un sistema, en cada unao de los métodos.
3. Para el caso puntual que mencionas, referido a la otra preguna, la cantidad de parámetros está bien definida así como su tipo de dato. Por lo tanto lo haría como @Einer.

> Mi duda es, si en
>   un hipotético caso es necesario pasar en algunos casos 1 argumento, en
>   otros 2 argumentos, en otro N argumentos, si es mejor esta resp.

4. Cuando el número de argumentos no es fijo, queriendo emular con un método como funciona php, a mi entender, esta respuesta sería más acertada.

Comment: Gracias Juan. O sea, según entiendo ¿hacerlo de esta manera aportaría más flexibilidad al código, dado que se pueden pasar o no varios argumentos opcionales y de varios tipos?

Comment: Es un recurso que se puede usar, pero fijate que perdés el chequeo de tipo de datos. En php esto es lo común pero no es la filosofía Java. Mas que algo que implementar en todos lados yo lo consideraría un recurso para alguna necesidad puntual.

Comment: Contestando tu pregunta, sí, podés pasar o no varios argumentos, y de varios tipos (usando Object como tipo de dato). No recuerdo haber probado esto pasando 0 argumentos, tal vez un argumento sea necesario, habría que probarlo.

Comment: No entiendo del todo lo que quieres decir con que *pierdo el chequeo del tipo de datos.*  En cuanto al uso, es para algo muy concreto ([planteado en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/219016/29967)). Realmente, es para dos tipos de casos, en uno llamaré al método pasándole un argumento `hourIndex`  y en otros llamaré al método sin ningún argumento. En ese sentido la respuesta de @Einer responde completamente a ese requerimiento. Mi duda es: si fueran varios casos de uso, pasando en algunos casos 1 argumento, en otros 2 argumentos, en otro N argumentos, si es mejor esta respuesta.

Comment: Edité la pregunta para responder las dudas del último comentario.