# String.xml - Texto con información en lista

Tags: string, textview

tengo un problema.
En una Activity necesito que aparezca cierta cantidad de información, algo similar a ésto:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at egestas dolor. Donec ut consectetur risus. Donec ipsum diam, viverra condimentum nisi in, accumsan viverra leo. Mauris vel condimentum lacus, non interdum massa. Aliquam lacus nulla, pharetra non pretium quis, tincidunt eget purus. Nulla facilisi. Integer imperdiet congue diam nec suscipit. Donec vulputate tempus arcu sit amet rhoncus. Phasellus placerat magna vitae erat ultrices vestibulum. Nulla velit mi, interdum at dapibus sit amet, volutpat ut felis. Suspendisse et congue nulla: "

Y que a su vez, abajo aparezca una lista, tipo:

1. Cosa x
2. Cosa x2
3. Cosa xn
   .
   .
   .

Y asi, muchos puntos, el problema es que solo me gustaría hacer un text view, no ocupar uno por cada punto de la lista ¿Es posible esto?

Comment: Sí, es posible. Concatenas todo en un `StrignBuilder` por ejemplo y luego haces algo como `mTextView.setText(sb);` donde `sb` sería tu `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es posible y además recomendable, ya que un `TextView` es una vista, y mientras más pongas más se sobrecarga la interfaz.

De hecho en las aplicaciones se suele usar un solo `TextView` para el contenido y si va a recibir valores tomados de varias partes conviene usar también un `StringBuilder` en vez de concatenar cadenas a mano, [como recomienda Android en su documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder). Para textos con diferentes colores y estilos se puede usar un `SpannableStringBuilder`<sup>1</sup>.

El único problema de `StringBuilder` es que no es *thread safe* (ver explicación sobre esto en el enlace anterior `^`), por lo que si esa activity depende de alguna sincronización, tendrías que usar `StringBuffer` en vez de `StrinBuilder`.

Veamos un ejemplo.

```
/*TextView y StringBuilder*/
TextView mTextView = findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

//Texto de un elemento en String.xml
String lorem = getResources().getString(R.string.lorem);
sb.append(lorem);

//Más adelante, en cualquier parte de la Activity
String lstOne="1. Dato uno"+System.getProperty("line.separator");
sb.append(lstOne);

//Más adelante, en cualquier parte de la Activity
String lstTwo="2. Dato dos"+System.getProperty("line.separator");
sb.append(lstTwo);

//Más adelante, en cualquier parte de la Activity
//Texto de un elemento en String.xml
String otroLorem = getResources().getString(R.string.otro_lorem);
sb.append(otroLorem);

//Cuando tengas todo
mTextView.setText(sb);
```

---

1. [Ver aquí un ejemplo de código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/219364/29967) donde se produce texto con varios colores mediante `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Comment: Oh vaya, lo solucioné colocando un Control Spinner, creo que se ajustaba a lo que esperaba.

De igual manera usaré ese metodo y a ver que tal me va. ¡Muchisimas gracias!